# MPAndroidChart - Remove Y axes first vlaue

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart (Line chart). In that my  y-Axes values are `(0,10,20,30,40,50)` vertically. I want to hide first value (here :0 is first value)?

- In chart i have left Axes and Bottom Axes, both are containing 0 value at first position.
- Y -axes(0,10,20,30,40,50)
- X- axes(0,10,20,30,40,50)

at the bottom left corner two  '0' are coming so i want to keep only single '0' for both X & Y Axes.

is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code by which you can hide left axis.

```
LineChart chart_line;

 chart_line.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
 chart_line.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
  // dont forget to refresh the drawing
 chart_line.invalidate();
```

But if you want to hide single value from array that not possible.
You need to remove that value from array.

Comment: My array size and value will be dynamic. but first value is fixed as '0'. so i just want remove first value. i don't want to remove all other value is it possible??

Comment: If first value is always 0 then you can remove that value from index 0.
otherwise not possible with MP Chart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .... , I added more information , is there any possibility to do this?